# Displaying member information from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

The code is about displaying membership information of all clients from database.  I was just wondering what I could do to improve/change it.

```
def optionA():
    global DoAnother
    while DoAnother == True:
        print("")
        member = input("Please enter the member number: ")
        if len(member) !=4:
            print ("")
            print("The member number is not valid")
            DoAnother = True
        else:
            global memberfile
            memberfile = open("members.txt","r+")
            searchMem = True
            for line in memberfile.readlines():
                listed = line.split(",")
                if member in listed:
                    print("")
                    print("Team Code: {0}".format(listed[0]))
                    print("Member number: {0}".format(listed[2]))
                    print("Date of joining: {0}".format(listed[1]))
                    print("Membership type: {0}".format(listed[3]))
                    print("Amount paid: {0}".format(listed[5]))
                    searchMem = False
                    nextchoice()
            if searchMem == True:
                optionA()

def optionB():
    print("")
    print("Team Code  Member No           Fee      Amount Paid      Amount Outstanding")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    global memberfile
    memberfile=open("members.txt","r+")
    amountOut = 0
    for line in memberfile.readlines():
        listed = line.split(",")

        if listed[3] =="F" and listed[5].strip('\n')<listed[4]:
            difference = (int(listed[4])-int(listed[5]))
            amountOut = (amountOut + difference)
            print("{0}          {1}             £{2}            £{3}          £{4}".format(listed[0], listed[2], listed[4], listed[5].strip('\n'), difference))
    print("")
    print("                                                         Total Outstanding: £{0}".format(amountOut))
    nextchoice()
```

Comment: What does your member.txt file look like?

Comment: choiseunghwan: You've left out a lot of code. What's the main loop look like? What does `next_choice()` do? How/where is`DoAnother` initialized? Also what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Please don't let us guess how you handle these functions. If you want a proper review, give us some proper code to be reviewed

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of issues with this code; the first two items below are seriously bad habits.

- **Inappropriate use of functions.**  Functions are not goto labels.  Having `optionA` call itself or `nextchoice()` makes no sense.  *This **must** be corrected — it is a fundamental misunderstanding of how to write programs.*
- **Use of global variables.**  If you design your functions properly, there should be no need for *any* global variables.
- **Lack of abstraction.**  There is nothing in common between these two functions, other than the fact that they both read from `members.txt`.  It would be a good idea to have a function to read, interpret, search the file.  Furthermore, since the data are in a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) format, you should use the Python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).
- **Using string comparison for numbers.** This is a bug:

  > ```
  > listed[5].strip('\n')<listed[4]
  > ```

  … because you are comparing numbers ASCIIbetically.
- **Lack of documentation.** `optionA` and `optionB` are both mysterious names for functions.  It's not immediately clear what the `members.txt` file looks like, or why `optionB` ignores rows whose membership type column is not `F`.
- **File descriptor leak.**  If you call `open()` without a corresponding call to `close()`, you might leak file descriptors.  In Python, you almost *always* want to call `open()` using a `with` block.
- **Member search by all attributes.** You ask the user to enter a member number.  However, when you do

  > ```
  > listed = line.split(",")
  > if member in listed:
  >     …
  > ```

  … you are actually searching *all* fields, not just the third column.
- **Python style guide.**  PEP 8, the official Python style guide, says that [variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) should be `lower_case_with_underscores` unless you have a good reason to deviate from the norm.

### Suggested solution

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

MEMBERS_TXT_FIELDS = [
    ('Team Code', str),
    ('Date of joining', str),
    ('Member number', str),
    ('Membership type', str),
    ('Fee', Decimal),
    ('Amount paid', Decimal),
]

def members(member_number=None):
    with open('members.txt') as member_file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(member_file)
        for row in csv_file:
            member = {
                field_name: conv(val)
                for (field_name, conv), val in zip(MEMBERS_TXT_FIELDS, row)
            }
            if member_number is None or member_number == member['Member number']:
                yield member

def show_single_member(member_number):
    for member in members(member_number):
        print("""
Team Code: {Team Code}
Member number: {Member number}
Date of joining: {Date of joining}
Membership type: {Membership type}
Amount paid: {Amount paid}""".format(**member))
        return True
    return False

def show_owing_members():
    def value_fmt(field_def, member):
        field_name, width = field_def
        value = member[field_name]
        if isinstance(value, Decimal):
            return "£{0}".format(value.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))).rjust(width - 1) + ' '
        else:
            return str(member[field_name]).ljust(width)

    TABLE_FIELDS = [
        # Field name, width
        ('Team Code', 11),
        ('Member number', 20),
        ('Fee', 9),
        ('Amount paid', 17),
        ('Amount outstanding', 31),
    ]

    # Print headings
    print(''.join(field.ljust(width) for field, width in TABLE_FIELDS))
    print(''.join('-' * width for field, width in TABLE_FIELDS))

    total_outstanding = Decimal('0.00')
    for member in members():
        if member['Membership type'] == 'F' and member['Amount paid'] < member['Fee']:
            member['Amount outstanding'] = member['Fee'] - member['Amount paid']
            print(''.join(value_fmt(field_def, member) for field_def in TABLE_FIELDS))
            total_outstanding += member['Amount outstanding']
    print()
    w = sum(width for field, width in TABLE_FIELDS if field != 'Amount outstanding')
    print("Total outstanding: ".rjust(w) + "£{0}".format(total_outstanding))


def menu():
    while True:
        print("A: Member lookup")
        print("B: Outstanding fees")
        print("Q: Quit")
        choice = input("Choice: ").upper()
        if choice == 'A':
            ok = show_single_member(input("Please enter the member number: "))
            if not ok:
                print("No such member")
        elif choice == 'B':
            show_owing_members()
        elif choice == 'Q':
            break
        print()
```

Comment: Hopefully he signs up and checks out this fineee solution !

Answer (score -1):

I would implement something more functional, that way if you go on to create a larger business program you could debug, and section your needs better.

```
#seperating the formatting/print function from the lookup would be alot cleaner
#and allow for long-term changes without having to mess with the parts that work

def getMemberInfo():

    #you also don't need loop values, rather keep testing bad input
    #as the looping mechanism
    member = input("Please enter the member number: ")
    while len(member) != 4:
        member = input("\nPlease enter a valid member number: ")

    #cleaner way to open files
    with open("members.txt", "r+") as memberFile:
        for line in memberFile:
            listed = line.split(",")
            if member in listed:

                #append the difference value, to avoid anything other
                #than formatting in the second function
                listed.append(int(listed[5]) - int(listed[4]))
                return listed

            #else:  read next line
        return(None) # member wasn't found in file       

def printMemberInfo( listed ):    
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Team Code: {0}".format(listed[0]))
    print("Member number: {0}".format(listed[2]))
    print("Date of joining: {0}".format(listed[1]))
    print("Membership type: {0}".format(listed[3]))
    print("Amount paid: {0}".format(listed[4]))

    #you can play around with the formatting
    #exceeding col: 80 was irking me

    print("{0} {1} £{2} £{3} £{4}".format( \
           listed[0], listed[2], listed[4], listed[5].strip('\n'), listed[6]))

    print("")
    print(" Total Outstanding: £{0}".format(listed[6]))
```

With this code, you could have something that determines what the user wants to do, maybe `getMemberInfo()`, `updateMemberInfo()`, `deleteMember()`, and then can call those respective functions inside a `main(): eventloop`!